# VLAN not working in ComNet switch

Tags: vlan, switching, trunk, switchport

I'm trying to configure VLANs with 3 switches ComNet (2- CNGE2FE8MSPOE +  1- CWGE26FX2TX24MSPOE) and it's not working as I expect. It's the first time that I work with VLAN and I don't know If I didn't understand it or not.

This is the installation:

**VLAN**

- 20 ==> CCTV
- 30 ==> Clients
- 40 ==> Server

**main SW - CWGE26FX2TX24MSPOE**

- Port 1 ==> all (20,30,40)
- Port 2 ==> 30
- Port 3 ==> all (20,30,40)
- Port 25 ==> all (20,30,40)=> switch 2
- Port 26 ==> all (20,30,40) => switch 3

**SW 2 - CNGE2FE8MSPOE**

- Port 1 ==> 20/40
- Port 2 ==> 20
- Port 7 ==> all (20,30,40) => switch 3
- Port 8 ==> all (20,30,40) ==> switch 2

**SW 3 - CNGE2FE8MSPOE**

- Port 1 ==> 20
- Port 2 ==> 20
- Port 7 ==> all (20,30,40) ==> switch 1
- Port 8 ==> all (20,30,40) ==> switch 2

If I setup the VLAN in the link ports I always see all, and if not I can't see anything.

Thanks in advance.

### **CNGE2FE8MSPOE screenshots**

[image: CNGE2FE8MSPOE - VLAN]
[image: CNGE2FE8MSPOE - VLAN Port based]

### **CWGE26FX2TX24MSPOE screenshots**

[image: CWGE26FX2TX24MSPOE - Ports]
[image: CWGE26FX2TX24MSPOE - VLAN Membership]

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Comment: Sorry, for a product to be on-topic here, the vendor needs to offer optional, paid support - see the [help].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VLANs partition your physical switch(es) into separate, logical switches. Nodes in different VLANs cannot talk to each other directly, they must use a router. The router needs to be connected to all VLANs it routes.

Between switches, a frame's VLAN association can be transported by an explicit tag (802.1Q) or by implicit understanding (both sides regard frames without a VLAN tag as belonging to VLAN *x*, sometimes called the port's *native VLAN*). Tagging and implicit understanding of untagged frames allow multiple VLANs to share a single, physical link between switches, a *VLAN trunk*. Of course, both sides need to agree on the VLANs used on a trunk.

Normal end nodes often don't understand VLAN tagging. Also, you likely won't want end nodes to be able to join any VLAN they won't. Accordingly, you configure the ports those end nodes are connected to as *access ports*: a single, untagged VLAN, and no tagged VLANs allowed.

In your screenshots, you're just using VLAN 1 as untagged on all ports. The other VLANs are defined but not used (much).

What you need to do:

1. configure links between switches as trunks, tagging all VLANs that you require to be transported (alternatively, a single VLAN may remain untagged)
2. configure links to end nodes with the single, untagged VLAN that you want that node to be connected to
3. as with the switches, trunk all active VLANs to a router and configure it to route between the VLANs (very often, a layer-3 switch in the network "core" is used for that, but your switches seem to be layer-2 only)